# For two connected open sets of n-sphere,if the union is n-sphere,then the intersection is also connected.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> For two connected open sets $U$ and $V$ of $S^n(n\geq 2)$,if $U \cup V=S^n$,then $U \cap V$ is also connected.

1.I have no idea how to use (reduced) singular homology groups to describe connectedness of topological spaces.I just know $ {H_0 ^\sim}(X)=0$ iff  X is path-connected.

2.As for the method of using degree map of $S^n$, I have trouble in constructing a good map.To be honest, again, I don't know how to describe connectedness.

Any hint will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: An open of $S^n$ is connected iff it is path connected.

Comment: Mayer-Vietoris?

Comment: @Nicolas Hemelsoet yeah, I forget this fact. If so, the question is easy. Thank you !

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown Right, just note that $(U,V)$ is a Mayer-Vietoris pair, thanks

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Sorry for such a late comment! Your comments are really helpful! Yet I’m thinking of how to prove that  **An open of $S^n$ is connected iff it is path connected.** My idea is that since $S^n$ is an $n$-dim’l smooth manifold, an open set $U$ of the sphere is an open submanifold. Since, for a manifold, connectedness is equivalent to path-connectedness, so $U$ is path-connected. Yet I’m wondering if we can prove the *simple* fact you commented without using facts related to smooth manifolds? (since it is a purely a topological question) Thank you for your comment again! :)

Answer (score 1):

First, by @Nicolas' comment connected and path-connected are equivalent in this context. As in @Lord's comment (and hence marking this answer cw), the Mayer-Vietoris sequence (in reduced homology) ends with
$$H_1(S^n) \to \tilde H_0(A \cap B) \to \tilde H_0(A) \oplus \tilde H_0(B) \to \tilde H_0(S^n)$$
Since $S^n$ is simply connected and assuming $A$ and $B$ are connected, this is an exact sequence
$$0 \to \tilde H_0(A \cap B) \to 0 \to 0$$
and hence $\tilde H_0(A \cap B) = 0$, which means $A \cap B$ is connected.